# What does the postfix of Nokia Lumia model number mean?

Tags: lumia

I see that some sellers are using postfixes for Nokia Lumia models but I don't know what these postfixes mean.

For example, there is Nokia Lumia 720 but there is also
Nokia Lumia 720.1
and
Nokia Lumia 720.2

What does .1 and .2 mean and is there some official list of those numeric postfixes?

Here are links to some Internet websites using those codes:
http://www.sahibinden.com/listing/alisveris-cep-telefonu-modeller-nokia-lumia-720.2-yil-distributor-garantili-128220728/detail

http://www.tehnoland.lv/lv/telefoni/mobilie-telefoni/nokia-lumia-720-1-white-112419
http://220.lv/lv/mobilie_telefoni/mobilie_telefoni/mobilais_telefons_nokia_2061_white_balts?id=370873

Those are mostly foreign sites, thus I suspect that these codes might have something to do with regions but I cannot find a list with all codes.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very strong indication that these numbers are not postfixes or anything meaningful. Instead, they are simply two sentences separated by a period.

[The first link you referenced is a Turkish site.](http://www.sahibinden.com/listing/alisveris-cep-telefonu-modeller-nokia-lumia-720.2-yil-distributor-garantili-128220728/detail) [This is the translation of the title.](http://translate.google.com/#tr/en/NOKIA%20LUMIA%20720.2%20YIL%20D%C4%B0STR%C4%B0B%C3%9CT%C3%96R%20GARANT%C4%B0L%C4%B0)

> NOKIA LUMIA 720.2 YIL DİSTRİBÜTÖR GARANTİLİ

translated to

> Nokia Lumia 720.2 YEAR WARRANTY DISTRIBUTORS

[For the second link](http://www.tehnoland.lv/lv/telefoni/mobilie-telefoni/nokia-lumia-720-1-white-112419), there seems to be an indication that there is 1 white Lumia 720 being sold.

Here is another example: if you Google `Lumia 720.2`, one of the results is:

[image]

I think you might be started to see what is happening.

Also, Nokia has a convention in place to give internal model numbers to phones. For example, the Lumia 720 has 2 versions- one is `RM-885` and the other is `RM-860`.

All in all, the ads for the Lumia 720 you are seeing are ads for the version of the Lumia 720 that is available in the region where the site is.

Comment: I doubt that because if you look at the web links, the postfix is also in the link itself in form of -1 and -2. Also I found another link in Latvia for Nokia 206.1 which has 2061 in the link: http://220.lv/lv/mobilie_telefoni/mobilie_telefoni/mobilais_telefons_nokia_2061_white_balts?id=370873  It would be weird for a web shop to put in the link the count of phones in their store. Someone made a suggestion that it's indeed the region code and .1 means Europe (thus .2 means Turkey or somwhere there) but I still cannot find any proof of that.

Comment: Here is even a Youtube review of the phone Nokia 208 with postfix .1 http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3ARBJeqNls and it's from Romania, thus .1 might indeed be for Europe.

Comment: Fair enough- the first line of my answer states "There is a very strong **indication**..."

Answer (score 4):

Finally I found one link which somewhat indirectly explains the differences. As this is not an official list from Nokia, I cannot mark this as answer to give someone a chance to find more credible source of information.

Here you go:

[Global Lumia 920 gets FCC certification](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/flow/item/15771_Global_Lumia_920_gets_FCC_cert.php)

> It's worth noting that Nokia's global variants are nearly always coded
>   .1, with region specific, and/or follow on devices coded .2, .3, .4
>   and so on.

And also I found that Nokia is putting these subcodes even on their boxes. But their box labeling politics seems confusing - some variants have IMEI on the box, some have warranty information, some have their RM-xxx model numbers, some have colour information (or maybe that's the name of their software update?) and some don't. Oh, Nokia, you should make it less confusing for your customers:

920.3 RM-820 for Rogers:
[http://i.imgur.com/z2aXCfR.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/z2aXCfR.jpg)

920.1 without RM-
[http://i.imgur.com/bJNm8.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/bJNm8.jpg)

One more 920.1 with some weird Wienthong sticker:
http://i736.photobucket.com/albums/xx5/dhb22081988/IMG_1046_zpseff1f417.jpg

And one more 920.1 with warranty info for Saudi Arabia:
http://main.makeuseoflimited.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/nokia-lumia-920-review-3.jpg